# Not understanding the path in distributed path

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

From the below code I didn't understand 2 things:

1. `DistributedCache.addcachefile(new URI ('/abc.dat'), job.getconfiguration())`

I didn't understand URI path has to be present in the HDFS. Correct me if I am wrong.

2. And what is `p.getname().equals()` from the below code:

   ```
   public class MyDC {

   public static class MyMapper extends Mapper < LongWritable, Text, Text, Text > {

       private Map < String, String > abMap = new HashMap < String, String > ();

       private Text outputKey = new Text();

       private Text outputValue = new Text();

       protected void setup(Context context) throws
       java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {

           Path[] files = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());

           for (Path p: files) {

               if (p.getName().equals("abc.dat")) {

                   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(p.toString()));

                   String line = reader.readLine();

                   while (line != null) {

                       String[] tokens = line.split("\t");

                       String ab = tokens[0];

                       String state = tokens[1];

                       abMap.put(ab, state);

                       line = reader.readLine();

                   }

               }

           }

           if (abMap.isEmpty()) {

               throw new IOException("Unable to load Abbrevation data.");

           }

       }

       protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
       throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {

           String row = value.toString();

           String[] tokens = row.split("\t");

           String inab = tokens[0];

           String state = abMap.get(inab);

           outputKey.set(state);

           outputValue.set(row);

           context.write(outputKey, outputValue);

       }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

       Job job = new Job();

       job.setJarByClass(MyDC.class);

       job.setJobName("DCTest");

       job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

       try {

           DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/abc.dat"), job.getConfiguration());

       } catch (Exception e) {

           System.out.println(e);

       }

       job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);

       job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

       job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);


       FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));

       FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

       job.waitForCompletion(true);

   }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DistributedCache is an API which is used to add a file or a group of files in the memory and will be available for every data-nodes whether the map-reduce will work. One example of using DistributedCache is map-side joins.

DistributedCache.addcachefile(new URI ('/abc.dat'), job.getconfiguration()) will add the abc.dat file in the cache area. There can be n numbers of file in the cache and p.getName().equals("abc.dat")) will check the file which you required. Every path in HDFS will be taken under Path[] for map-reduce processing. For example :

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));

FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
```

The first Path(args[0]) is the first argument
(input file location)  you pass while Jar execution and Path(args[1]) is the second argument which the output file location. Everything is taken as Path array.

In the same way when you add any file to cache it will get arrayed in the Path array which you shud be retrieving using the below code.

Path[] files = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());

It will return all the files present in the cache and you will your file name by p.getName().equals() method.

Comment: Thanks ishan for that !! It was of great help

Answer (score 1):

The idea of Distributed Cache is to make some static data available to the task node before it starts its execution.

File has to be present in HDFS ,so that it can then add it to the Distributed Cache (to each task node)

DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFile basically gets all the cache files present in that task node. By `if (p.getName().equals("abc.dat")) {` you are getting the appropriate Cache File to be processed by your application.

Please refer to the docs below:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#DistributedCache

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html#getLocalCacheFiles(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)