# 2 mappers, each for its own source directory --> one reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have 2 data sources, each storing data in a different format.

Each should be handled by a different mapper, but both mappers will arrive at the same intermediate format to pass to the reducer.

I know I can handle multiple inputs by adding multiple "-input" options to hadoop streaming, but how to assign separate mapper for each input?

Comment: [MultipleInputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html)

Comment: @dust , refer to this SE post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229646/hadoop-mapreduce-multiple-input-output-paths/37229864#37229864

Comment: @Ravindrababu, I have seen this answer, but my question is how to do the same using hadoop-streaming. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop's InputFormat contains one class "MultipleInputs". This is used to add multiple input files which can be processed by more than one Mapper. Below is the syntax.

MultipleInputs.addInputpath(job,path,inputformatClass,1stMapperClass);
MultipleInputs.addInputpath(job,path,inputformatClass,2stMapperClass);

The output of both the mapper will be processed by one reducer..
_____________________________OR_______________________________________

You can use DistributedCache API of map-reduce, where one file can be stored into memory and you can perform map-side joins. You can go to the below url..

[Not understanding the path in distributed path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37246043/not-understanding-the-path-in-distributed-path/37254505#37254505)

PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF IT HELPS>

Comment: Thank you for answering ishan, but as explained in my question (and tags), this was about hadoop-streaming rather than pure hadoop Java implementation. Thank you again anyway.